# Problem configuring the Calendar module

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm having trouble with Drupal 7 and the calendar (version 7.x-1.0-alpha3) module. The default view is working. It is showing the nodes based on the time they were updated.

I added a date field called time1 to a basic page node type. I added some basic pages with date set for the current date.

I don't know how to make the calendar show the nodes based on the value of time1. I've tried to change the argument as in the picture.

[image]
The README.txt of the module says that look the documentation on the project page. However, there is no documentation that applies to Drupal 7 in here http://drupal.org/node/262062

Has someone drupal 7 and the calendar working? What am I doing wrong here?

I don't know could this be related to http://drupal.org/node/1096224
For me none of the month, week or day views are working.

Comment: Have you tried running the dev version of Calendar? The alpha 3 release is nearly 3 months old, and a lot has changed in Views and the Date modules since then.

Comment: You could also try the [FullCalendar](http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) module if you want a jQuery based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views 3 has been completely changed; the API has been rewritten. Make sure Calendar is compatible with that version of Views.
Check the [Calendar issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/calendar?categories=All) to see if there are reported issue.

Comment: Yes, Calendar's alpha3 was January 20, and oh, so much has changed since then with views 3. I think most modules have at least some problem with their views 3 integration.

Comment: cool, glad to have helped.  Pretty annoying if you ask me to just completely revamp it,  they should've just skipped to version 4 to make it less confusing.